# How do I fix a merge conflict due to removal of a file in a using cherry-pick?

Tags: bash, git

```
 git cherry-pick --strategy=recursive -X theirs -n "$GitHub_SHA"
```

Hello, I'm specifying -s recursive -X theirs, why is it still necessary to git rm and git add?

Also how do i differentiate when to git rm or git add in my bash script?

```
git cherry-pick --strategy=recursive -X theirs -n "$GitHub_SHA" || merge_conflict=1

   if [ ${merge_conflict:-0} -eq 1 ]
    then
    git add -all
   fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-X theirs` and `-X ours` act on conflicting hunks. If a file has been removed by one side, no conflicting hunks are generated. At the same time, the context lines are not generated either. Without the hunks and context lines, the strategy option cannot pick lines.

To differentiate one conflicting type from another, you could try `git status -s` and parse the result in short format. For details on short format, see [Short Format](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-status#_short_format). For example, for a `deleted by us` file `foo.txt`, `git status -s foo.txt` prints `DU foo.txt`. For `both modified`, it's `UU foo.txt`.